# Is it possible to partially populate Jtable with values from database

Tags: java, swing, jtable

What I wanted to know is that is it possible that Jtable fills say 4 out of 5 fields from database and the 5th field remains static.(In the sense that say the 5th field has button for all rows. based on the value of a particular field, the button when pressed displays different popups). So is it possible for such kind of requirement ? If so kindly provide me with some working examples.

Comment: Google "jtable  jdbc"

Comment: No one will provide you with any example until you show you tried to make it yourself and post your relevant code. Did you even try to search the site?

Comment: Yes, your requirement is possible.  Search for JTable sparse model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But what I wanted to know is that is it possible that Jtable fills say 4 out of 5 fields from database and the 5th field remains static

Normally when you have code to load data from a data base you load the data from a ResultSet by creating a Vector to contain the data for each row from the database. Something like:

```
while (rs.next())
{
  Vector row = new Vector(columns);

  for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
  {
      row.addElement( rs.getObject(i) );
  }

  row.addElement( your statice element here ); // extra column

  data.addElement( row );
}
```

So you just need to add data for the extra column. Of course when you create the "column names" for the DefaultTableModel you will also need to create an extra column for the heading.

> the 5th field has button for all rows

You may want to check out [Table Button Column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) for a button renderer/editor.